# Srss Report #error

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to get a column in a report, and I am having the issue where the report will show #error in the column. I think I have found the cause, but I am unsure, and I'm also unsure how to solve it.

The code I am currently using is:

```
=iif(SUM(Fields!ask_response.Value)>SUM(Fields!ask_totalduration.Value), "Time Met", "Time not Met")
```

Some of the values have 0 in the one of the 2 columns involved. Is there a way to get it to say "Time Not Met" if the value is 0?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: This is the code that I have at present. It is causing me problems with the #error. `=iif(SUM(IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ask_response.Value),0,Fields!ask_response.Value))
<(SUM(IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ask_totalduration.Value),0,Fields!ask_totalduration.Value))), "Time Met", "Time not Met")`

Answer (score 0):

Nested IIf's are a true pain and I have had similar issues before. Copy this to a new location and start over, working your way from the inside out, testing at each level to make sure you do not get an error.

I am not sure you should be using sum in this instance.

I am not sure if this will work but I have...

```
=iif(IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ask_response.Value),0,Fields!ask_response.Value) > IIf(IsNothing(Fields!ask_totalduration.Value),0,Fields!ask_totalduration.V‌​alue),"Time Met", "Time not Met" )
```